# How to set up directX with codeblocks

Tags: directx, codeblocks

I really need to figure out how to set up the directX SDK with code::blocks.
I've looked at lots of tutorials but none of them work for me and I cant figure out how to do it myself. When ever I try to compile a program, codeblocks says stuff like "strsafe.h no such file or directory".
I've installed everything but I think the problem is that codeblocks doesn't know where to find the SDK. If someone could help that would be really great. Thanks in advance.  :-)

Comment: The short answer is: You don't need and shouldn't use the legacy DirectX SDK. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-). The Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK already have all the required headers for DirectX 11 development, along with the D3DCompile API for HLSL and the FXC.EXE HLSL compiler. For everything else, see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

Comment: I'm using windows 7 though

Comment: The Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK both fully support Windows 7. They support Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7, Windows 8.x, and Windows 10 for Win32 desktop for targeting applications. Windows 7 supports DirectX 11.0 by default, and you can get DirectX 11.1 for it as well--see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/). The *only* case where you'd still use the legacy DirectX SDK is if you want to use XAudio2.7 on Windows 7. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8/).

Comment: The choice of which platform you target with the Windows SDK is based on the preprocessor symbol ``_WIN32_WINNT`` which you can set to ``0x0601`` if you want Windows 7 compatible headers. See [Using the Windows headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers).